# Deshabilitar un botón desde el Controller en ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-core

les queria realizar una consulta es posible bloquear un boton desde un controller en .net sin necesidad de usar javascript?

Controller:

```
    public IActionResult Upload()
    {           
        ViewData["#btnUpload"] = true;  
        return View();  
    }
```

HTML:

```
<button disabled="disabled" id="btnUpload" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
```

lo que quiero es deshabilitar el boton pero desde el controller si es posible, se que se puede hacer con javascript pero por temas de desarrollo y tecnología no lo puedo hacer.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a HTML disabled? Por otro lado, revisa esta lectura recomedada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: no no me refiero al html, me refiero al controler directamente, si efectivamente seria colocar un disable pero desde el controller

Comment: coloca un `viewData.DeshabilitarBoton = true` y si recién estás iniciando, te sugiero revisar este workshop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Comment: entiendo lo del viewdata pero como lo agrego directamente al id del boton? efectivamente estoy iniciando y me excuso si no entiendo aun las instrucciones dadas

Comment: Edita la pregunta, agrega el código que tienes, lo que has intentado :D

Comment: Este es mi Boton:
<button disabled="disabled" id="btnUpload" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>

este es el controlador :
public IActionResult Upload()
        {
            
            ViewData["#btnUpload"] = true;
return view();
}

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/327309/edit dale click ahí y procede a editar la pregunta

Comment: listo @fredyfx fue editada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te en cuenta que ASP.NET MVC **NO** funciona como ASP.NET Web Forms, o sea, desde el código de Servidor (Controller) **no puedes** acceder directamente a los controles HTML por su Id.

Lo que puedes hacer es indicar en el Controlador (mediante `ViewData` por ejemplo..) si el botón estará habilitado o deshabilitado cuando se renderize la Vista.

En el **Controlador**:

```
ViewData["btnUploadDisabled"] = true;
```

Y en la **Vista**:

```
@if (ViewData["btnUploadDisabled"].ToString() == "true") // o también ((bool)ViewData["btnUploadDisabled"] == true)
{
    <button disabled="disabled" id="btnUpload" type="submit" class="btn btn- primary">Upload File</button>
}
else
{
    <button id="btnUpload" id="btnUpload" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Controlador:

```
public IActionResult Upload() { 
    ViewData["DeshabilitarBoton"] = true; 
    return view(); 
}
```

En tu vista:

```
<button  id="btnUpload" @{ ((bool)ViewData["DeshabilitarBoton"]) ? "disabled='disabled'" : ""} type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
```

Este documento te será de ayuda: http://fredyfx.com/post/tutorial-microsoft-webmatrix-sintaxis-razor/

Comment: Gracias por la info, sin embargo aun con el código que me pasaste no me bloquea el botón.

Comment: Click derecho, inspeccionar elemento y mira lo que se genera en el HTML

Comment: @fredyfx: Te falta el Cast amigo, `ViewData` devuelve un `Object`: `@{ ((bool)ViewData["DeshabilitarBoton"]) ? "disabled='disabled'" : ""}` ;)

Comment: gracias bro, se me pasó :D

Comment: Gracias a los dos sin embargo en el codigo que me envian casteado me genero al inicio un error que se esperaba una coma y luego de que le agregue la coma me sale el siguiente error "Solo las expresiones de asignacion, llamada, incremento, decremento, espera y objeto nuevo se pueden usar como una instruccion" ese error se genera en el Html

Comment: `""} type="submit"` Aquí me parece que olvidé agregar el punto y coma: `"";} type="submit"`

Comment: @WilliamAvella: Probaste el ejemplo que te indiqué en mi respuesta?.

Comment: Si efectivamente pero tampoco lo bloquea